# Debugging Android with GDB

Tags: android

I am trying to debug rild.c deamon with gdb.I followed the steps given in developer site with respect to gdbserver and gdb.After the connection is established between gdbserver and gdb in localhost iam not able to step in GDB i,e when i give next or Step command in gdb it simply hangs.can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging native applications of AOSP can be quite challenging. You need right combination of gdbserver and gdb to get it working. AOSP site has little info on native debugging.

Please check [Debugging Android native applications](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html). It explains this in step by step tutorial with troubleshooting tips.