# Debugging native android code without ndk-gdb?

Tags: android, gdb

We have been using a custom build system for years, naturally when we decided to support android the first step was porting our build system. We have had everything up and working for awhile with the exception of native debugging. Unfortunately when you don't use Google's native build system ndk-gdb doesn't work. Does anybody know how to get gdb working on a device without using the ndk-gdb script?

Comment: Please check my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822693/debugging-android-with-gdb.